# What do I do with a private key and a .ppk file to log into a remote client?

Tags: macos, ssh, unix, osx-lion

I am new to SSH and I have to log into a remote client. The owner of that client sent me a private key in a text file and a .ppk file. How do I use these to login?

I'm running OS X Lion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `ppk` file if you don't use PuTTY. Instead, save the plain text private key to a file.

```
mkdir -p ~/.ssh
open -e ~/.ssh/my-key
```

Paste the key there, and save. Now make it readable by your user only:

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/my-key
```

Then, use SSH to connect:

```
ssh user@host -i ~/.ssh/my-key
```

Answer (score 0):

try typing

`ssh user@<target server> -i /path/to/key/file`